# Mongoose add default Array Object to Sub Array when record add to the collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

I want to add an Array Object to Sub array as default value when adding record to the collection. below please find my chema

```
const JobSpecificetionSchema = new Schema({
 ACTIVITY:[{
    DESCRIPTION: { type: String, default: '' },
    SUB_ACTIVITY:[{
      DESCRIPTION: { type: String, default: '' },
      REPEAT_TYPE: { type: String, default: '' },// 1 - inspection will start 2 - inspection will not start
      FREQUENCY: { type: String, default: '' }, // 1 - weekly, 2 - monthly, 3 - yearly
      PAR_1: { type: String, default: '' }, // if weekly, then every one week or two. then monthly every one month or two months
      PAR_2: { type: String, default: '' }, // if weekly then days in the week. ie (Monday 1, tue 2) (1,2,3)  Monthly- day ie 25  yearly- month ie 1 to 12
      PAR_3: { type: String, default: '' }, // if yearly then day 25
      ASSIGNEE_WORKERS:[{
        ASSIGNEE_ID : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, default: '000000000000000000000000' },
      }]
    }]
  }]

});
```

You can see i want to add a default array to **ASSIGNEE_WORKERS** array when i create a record to this collection.

The current way doesn't work. please help for this

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "pre save" hook and assign your default array there if it is a new document (isNew property on the document, the document itself being accessible as "this" within the pre save hook) if that is what you want.

Comment: can you give me some example please